# Creating ABL Client to Consume a REST Web Service

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm not finding any documentation on connecting to a REST web service from progress. Can someone please point me in the direction of documentation or provide a connection example.

Progress: 11.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with 11.5.1 there's built in support for consuming REST webservices in a controlled way. But since you're not on that version I will leave that out *for now*.

Unless upgrading is an option you can do several things:

**Call a OS program for HTTP like curl or wget**

How to do this exactly will depend of utility of choice, os, version etc. Also be advised that os updates might change the behavior.

Also you should look into error redirecting etc before doing this. Calling out to the OS will create a second process so it might impact system resources. Use only if you take those things in account.

On the other side it's easy and fast. Curl is also highly flexible and will help with whatever headers or other things you might want to use.

You could also look into calling the curl library directly instead. Be advised that you will heavily rely on mempointers and other c-like structures in that case!

```
PROCEDURE curl:
  DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcUrl      AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
  DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER pcResponse AS LONGCHAR    NO-UNDO.

  DEFINE VARIABLE cCommand AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

  /* -s is for silent use - show no errors or feedback on the screen */
  cCommand = "curl -s " + pcUrl + " > /tmp/curl.txt".

  OS-COMMAND NO-CONSOLE VALUE(cCommand).

  COPY-LOB FROM FILE "/tmp/curl.txt" TO pcResponse .
END.

DEFINE VARIABLE lc AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.

run curl("http://www.google.com/", OUTPUT lc).

MESSAGE STRING(SUBSTRING(lc,1,100)) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

**Use .net classes**

I have no knowledge in .net so I can't help you with code for this. You will have to research how to call webservices in .Net to start with and then "translate" into ABL. This will only work on Windows - Progress have no support for Mono or other ways of doing .net in other OSes.

**Roll your own using sockets**

Shamelessly stolen example from: [Progress Knowledgebase](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P125506).

```
DEFINE VARIABLE vcHost     AS CHARACTER    INITIAL "localhost"   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE vcPort     AS CHARACTER    INITIAL "8080"        NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE vhSocket   AS HANDLE                             NO-UNDO.


CREATE SOCKET vhSocket.
vhSocket:CONNECT('-H ' + vcHost + ' -S ' + vcPort) NO-ERROR.

IF vhSocket:CONNECTED() = FALSE THEN
DO:
    MESSAGE "Connection failure" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

    MESSAGE ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    RETURN.
END.
ELSE
   MESSAGE "Connect"
       VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

vhSocket:SET-READ-RESPONSE-PROCEDURE('getResponse').
/* supposes there is an webspeed app called yourapp.w that receives param1, param2, param3 */
RUN PostRequest (
    INPUT '/scripts/cgiip.exe/WService=wsbroker1/yourApp.w', 
    INPUT 'param1=value&param2=value&param3=value'
    ).

WAIT-FOR READ-RESPONSE OF vhSocket. 
vhSocket:DISCONNECT() NO-ERROR.
DELETE OBJECT vhSocket.
QUIT.

PROCEDURE getResponse:
    DEFINE VARIABLE vcWebResp    AS CHARACTER        NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE lSucess      AS LOGICAL          NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE mResponse    AS MEMPTR           NO-UNDO.

    IF vhSocket:CONNECTED() = FALSE THEN do:
        MESSAGE 'Not Connected' VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
        RETURN.
    END.
    lSucess = TRUE.

    DO WHILE vhSocket:GET-BYTES-AVAILABLE() > 0:

         SET-SIZE(mResponse) = vhSocket:GET-BYTES-AVAILABLE() + 1.
         SET-BYTE-ORDER(mResponse) = BIG-ENDIAN.
         vhSocket:READ(mResponse,1,1,vhSocket:GET-BYTES-AVAILABLE()).
         vcWebResp = vcWebResp + GET-STRING(mResponse,1).
    END.
    /*
    *PUT HERE THE CODE TO MANIPULATE THE ANSWER
    */

END.
PROCEDURE PostRequest:
    DEFINE VARIABLE vcRequest      AS CHARACTER.
    DEFINE VARIABLE mRequest       AS MEMPTR.
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER postUrl AS CHAR. 
    /* URL that will send the data. It must be all the path after the server.  IE:/scripts/cgiip.exe/WService=wsbroker1/myApp.htm */
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER postData AS CHAR.
    /* Parameters to be sent in the format paramName=value&paramName=value&paramName=value */
    vcRequest =
        'POST ' +
        postUrl +
        ' HTTP/1.0~r~n' +
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded~r~n' +
        'Content-Length:' + string(LENGTH(postData)) +
        '~r~n' + '~r~n' +
        postData + '~r~n'.

    MESSAGE vcREquest
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

    SET-SIZE(mRequest)            = 0.
    SET-SIZE(mRequest)            = LENGTH(vcRequest) + 1.
    SET-BYTE-ORDER(mRequest)      = BIG-ENDIAN.
    PUT-STRING(mRequest,1)        = vcRequest .

    vhSocket:WRITE(mRequest, 1, LENGTH(vcRequest)).
END PROCEDURE.
```